# For-loop how to do

Tags: r

How can I do a for-loop to obtain 9 values and put in order in a rows? I have 9 columns in especificaciones.

I have this code but I don´t know how to continue.

```
ander <- list()
for(i in 1:length(consumos$Especificaciones)){
  url <- consumos$Especificaciones[i]
  ander[[i]] = read_html(url)


}


for(i in i:length())
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @Ander Milani, welcome to stack overflow. Please, could you provide a reproducible example? Like a data frame to try to solve your question. What have you done so far? what do you mean by obtain 9 values? the first 9 values? what order (asc/desc)?

Comment: Hello Alexis, I have 9 links like this -> http://multimedia.globomatik.net/productsSheet/A0023294.    I want to obtain the html code and then put all the html text in a new columm.